# How do I disable a plugin enforced by my host (in mu-plugins)?

Tags: plugins

My host makes mandatory two plugins which get automatic updates under mu-plugins folder.

Is there a way I can disable them with some trick, for example with a plugin folder of the same name under my local plugins folder or by duplicating some function and make them empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You disable mu-plugins by removing the plugin file from the `mu-plugins` directory. They are outside the normal plugin activation/deactivation cycle ["and cannot be disabled except by removing the plugin file from the must-use directory, which is found in wp-content/mu-plugins by default."](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) I assume you don't have the authority to remove the files.

The plugins may be using hooks and you may be able to remove some actions or filters and disable all or part of the plugins functionality, but without knowing how the mu-plugins work it is impossible to say how.

But... I suspect your host would ***shut down your site*** if you succeed in circumventing something they *require*. I imagine that requirement to be somewhere in your Terms of Service and not really a surprise to you. If you don't like the requirement, get another host.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the files with ftp or file manager, and use the disable wp update plugin to stop bluehost doing automatic updates
Bluehost have been affecting my site with their endurance-page-cache plugin, so i had to remove it.
I went into my cp file manager and deleted it. Sit is ok for now, will see if Bluehost suspend the site for doing it i will change hosts, as the plugin causes problems.
Here is the file you probably have as an mu-plugin
https://github.com/bluehost/endurance-page-cache/commit/fc66c1963adef251bd0741acb1827d5cbc19941b

Answer (score 0):

Simplest form is to lock the mu-pugin folder (if you have FTP rights). But in reality, Switching hosts won't help in the long run and neither will plugins that fight the bloatware MU-plugins. To answer your question, don't move to another WP-host. They're all the same, with just different problems... it drove me nut when I was 14. Instead, you should look into running your own server, the way you want it. There are many resources on youtube that have helped me throughout the years.

I run my own WP site(s), each with a dedicated Ubuntu server, 1GB of RAM, 1Tb both up/down, 25gb of storage, free SSL, firewalls AND most important I do backups, and this all costs me $5-6/month.

Interestingly, just recently one of my servers got this bloatware. In my case, my firewall decided to have a mind of its own, by doing so it installed bloatware and partially blamed WordPress. Why? It didn't believe it was protected by SSL. I know this since I checked on on the logs.